# Opening New Window using Menu Tab cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I am new to Mac os x and am having some difficulties with the the transition from windows and widgets. In my MainMenu.xib, I have the main window of my app, call it window A, and I added a menu tab to the main menu tabs as well as a new window B to the MainMenu.xib. When I launch my app, I want window A to open (which it does) and then when the user clicks the new menu tab, I want window B to appear. Is there an easy to way to connect the menu tab to window B in the IB so that it opens when the menu tab is clicked?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

What are main menu tabs? 
To show Window B call [myWindowB makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender].

Answer (score 0):

For window B , uncheck `visible at lunch` from interface builder(window attribute). when the user clicks the new menu tab.

```
[WindowA orderOut:sender];
[WindowB makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
```

write this code.